# Specifying Class style for Menu

Tags: menus, css

Im integrating Superfish into WP. I have called the CSS and the JS. However when I place a class style in the `wp_menu` as below, the menu is disappearing ([see here for rendered output](http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/)). Could anyone assist (this has been followed [from a not so helpful tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/widgets/integrating-superfish-menu-into-a-template/))

Current code being generated is:

```
<div class="menudiv">
<div class="sf-menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/">Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-101">    <a href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/?page_id=101">test 1</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-105"><a href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/?page_id=105">test 2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-103"><a href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/?page_id=103">test 3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-98"><a href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/?page_id=98">Test Page</a></li></ul></div>
</div>
```

Inside my header is the below:-

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'primary',
'container_class' => 'menudiv',
'menu_class' => 'sf-menu'
) );
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disappearing"? Is the menu markup being generated in the rendered output, and being hidden via CSS, or is the menu markup itself not getting rendered?

Comment: Hi Chip, the menu itself is not getting rendered.. please see the site rusticblonde.hostizzo.com... its as if the menu disappears when i placed the menu_class in there.

Comment: View browser source. The menu markup **is** being rendered.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. WordPress is outputting the menu markup, with specified CSS class. This is thus a **CSS/Superfish** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Hi Chip, i assumed that... but why isnt it displaying thou? It should do surely :S

Comment: Hi Chip, Can u help at all? End of the day that is all the tutorial does, calls the js, calls the CSS? but surely the menu disappearing is to do with the calling?

Comment: What Superfish tutorial are you working from? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your rendered output:

```
<div class="menu sf-menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item">...
```

It appears that `'sf-menu'` got appended as a class to the menu *container*, rather than to the *menu itself*.

The [**`wp_nav_menu()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function has two separate parameters:

- `menu_class`: CSS class applied to the menu list `<ul>` menu tag
- `container_class`: CSS class applied to the element tag that *contains* the menu (defaults to `<div>`)

So, if you use:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container_class' => 'menu-container-class',
    'menu_class' => 'menu-ul-class'
) );
```

The rendered output should look like:

```
<div class="menu menu-container-class"><ul class="menu-ul-class"><li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item">...
```

So, it *appears* that you've used `container_class` instead of `menu_class` in your `wp_nav_menu()` call.

### Edit

Replace this:

```
<div class="menudiv">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menudiv' => 'menu sf-menu' ) ); ?> 
</div>
```

...with this:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container_class' => 'menudiv',
    'menu_class' => 'sf-menu'
) );
?>
```

### Edit 2

Okay, I think I see what's happening: you don't have a custom menu *assigned* to the `'primary'` Template Location, which means that the default fallback menu (`wp_page_menu()`) is being output. When that happens, `'menu_class'` gets assigned to a `<div>` that contains the `wp_page_menu()` output, instead of to the `<ul>`.

You can tell that the default menu callback is being output, because of the CSS classes generated in your menu:

```
li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"
```

If this were an actual, custom menu in this location, those classes would include `'menu-item'`, instead of `'page_item'`. For reference, compare the [**CSS classes output by `wp_nav_menu()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes) with the [**CSS classes output by `wp_page_menu()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes).

Based on our chat conversation, the problem is that you're *registering* a Theme Location `main` in `register_nav_menus()`, but attempting to *call* a Theme Location `primary` in `wp_nav_menu()`. Easy fix, change `'theme_location' => 'primary'` to `'theme_location' => 'main'` in `wp_nav_menu()`:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main',
    'container_class' => 'menudiv',
    'menu_class' => 'sf-menu'
) );
?>
```

Comment: So for example if i have a class named menudiv... i would that in the container class?

Comment: To what HTML element do you want to apply that CSS class? If you want to apply `menudiv` class to the `<div>` tag that contains the menu, then yes.

Comment: Ok Chip... please see amends... it now displays the menu again... but not the styles !!! ARGH!

Comment: Basically the class of the menu is .sf menu (which is the superfish default style) and i want it in the DIV menudiv... so i amended as above and it brought the menu back... just no style to it :S

Comment: There is no `'menudiv'` parameter for `wp_nav_menu()`. Please refer to the [**`wp_nav_menu()`** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: I assume its down to the registering of the menu in my functions?

Comment: No, your menu is registered just fine, and is being rendered. You're just not applying the right CSS classes to the right HTML elements.

Comment: this is the tut... http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/widgets/integrating-superfish-menu-into-a-template/

Comment: ok... so laymens terms... ill be honst and say im lost how to sort... :S

Comment: See edited answer. Replace your current code with the suggested replacement. Then take a look at the rendered output, and make sure that the `'sf-menu'` class is being applied to the **`<ul>`** tag, and *not* to the `<div>` tag.

Comment: Hi Chip, Its not applying it to the UL tag.. its applying it to another DIV :S and its making the menu disappear :S

Comment: Its basically outputting the editted above.

Comment: First: can you please edit your original question whenever you add in clarifying information, or updated information (such as links to the tutorial, link to your live site, updated code that you tried, and *what worked/didn't work with that code*? Second: it doesn't look like you replaced the code exactly as suggested. Please paste your exact code into your question.

Comment: Chip i replaced it exactly as you suggested... replacing the bits where the div was a different name? Please see above, sorry for the questions

Comment: Chip the above edit made the menu again disappear :S

Comment: Your code is generating *two* `<div>` elements, instead of the expected *one* `<div>` element. Please paste your exact, current code into your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6474/discussion-between-chip-bennett-and-kirsty-harris)

Comment: *"the above edit made the menu again disappear"* - at this point, I have no idea which "above edit" you're referring to. Please see the bolded link, and join me in chat.

Comment: Hi Chip, ok which room, and thankyou, this means alot

Comment: See edited answer. I think we've got this one nailed now.

Comment: Can I delete this overly long comment thread?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing comma. I am pretty sure I have seen that produce an error in some cases. Besides, its just neater.

When you insert the `menu_class` you overwrite the default. I am pretty sure you are just seeing a consequence of that. Add both 'sf-menu' and 'menu`, or whatever classes your theme requires.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu sf-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: HI s_ha_dum... this still isnt working... its still not displaying the menu :S

Comment: Hi S_ha_dum, please can you elaborate on the above please? If you view my code rusticblonde.hostizzo.com... its just not displaying it... although the js and the css are loaded :S

Comment: You menu is there. I can see it in the source. It just isn't styled. I mean, your stylesheet it all but empty. It has one rule-- `body {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
}` This is really a CSS question, not a WordPress one.

Comment: yh but if i call the superfish menu.css... then surely it should be calling the style?

Comment: superfish does load its CSS but that CSS doesn't operate in a vacuum. Take a look at @chip-bennett's answer. See if that helps.